# Redux Form - Initial values to a component within a redux form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Novice.

I have a redux form component called Client. There is a sub component in that form called `Address`. `Address` is called in client as follows:

```
      <FormSection name="Address">
        <Address />
      </FormSection>
```

`Address` is in the form of `AddressContainer` and `Address`.

I am setting initial values for the Client redux form as follows:

```
  let ClientForm = reduxForm({
    form: CLIENT_FORM_NAME
  })(Client);

  let ClientForm2 = connect(
    (state, ownProps) => ({
      initialValues: ownProps.isEditMode ? state.editClient : {}, // pull initial values from client reducer
      enableReinitialize: true
    }),
    { reducer } // bind client loading action creator
  )(ClientForm);

  export default ClientForm2;
```

However the `Address` component does not get any of the initial state set in it.

How do you, in redux form, pass the initial state down from the main form to the its sub components - in this case `Address`?

**AddressContainer:**

```
  import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
  import { connect } from "react-redux";
  import { Field, change } from "redux-form";
  import { Col, Panel, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
  import Select from "react-select";

  import Address from "./address";
  import { getSuburbs, ensureStateData } from "./actions";

  import FormField from "../formComponents/formField";
  import TextField from "../formComponents/textField";
  import StaticText from "../formComponents/staticText";

  import { CLIENT_FORM_NAME } from "../clients/client/client";

  export class AddressContainer extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      _reduxForm: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      this.state = {
        selectedSuburb: null
      };
    }

    // Manage Select.Async for new data request - for suburbs.
    handleSuburbSearch = query => {
      const { addressData } = this.props;
      const companyStateId = addressData.companyStateId;

      if (!query || query.trim().length < 2) {
        return Promise.resolve({ options: [] });
      }
      const queryString = {
        query: query,
        companyStateId: companyStateId
      };
      return getSuburbs(queryString).then(data => {
        return { options: data };
      });
    };

    // Update the current state with the selected suburb.
    onSuburbStateChange = value => {
      this.setState({ selectedSuburb: value });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.ensureStateData();
    }

    render() {
      const { initialValues, addressData, updatePostcodeValue } = this.props;

      const { value } = this.state;
      const sectionPrefix = this.context._reduxForm.sectionPrefix;

      if (addressData.isLoading || !addressData.states.length) {
        return <p>Loading</p>;
      }
      if (addressData.error) {
        return <p>Error loading data</p>;
      }

      console.group("InitalValues Address");
      const companyStateId = addressData.companyStateId;
      console.log("companyStateId:", companyStateId);
      initialValues.Address = {
        ...initialValues.Address,
        state: addressData.states.find(
          option => option.stateId === companyStateId
        )
      };
      console.log(
        "addressData.states.Find: ",
        addressData.states.find(option => option.stateId === companyStateId)
      );
      console.log("addressData.states: ", initialValues.Address.state);
      console.log("initialValues.Address: ", initialValues.Address);
      console.log("initialValues: ", initialValues);
      console.groupEnd();

      return (
        <Address
          initialValues={initialValues}
          handleSuburbSearch={this.handleSuburbSearch}
          onSuburbStateChange={this.onSuburbStateChange}
          updatePostcodeValue={updatePostcodeValue}
          addressData={addressData}
          sectionPrefix={sectionPrefix}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    initialValues: state.editClient,
    companyStateId: state.companyStateId,
    addressData: state.addressData
  });

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    ensureStateData: () => dispatch(ensureStateData()),
    getSuburbs: values => dispatch(getSuburbs(values)),
    updatePostcodeValue: (postcode, sectionPrefix) =>
      dispatch(
        change(
          CLIENT_FORM_NAME,
          `${sectionPrefix ? sectionPrefix + "." : ""}postcode`,
          postcode
        )
      )
  });
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddressContainer);
```

**Address:**

```
  import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
  import { connect } from "react-redux";
  import { Field, change, reduxForm } from "redux-form";
  import { Col, Panel, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
  import Select from "react-select";
  import { getSuburbs } from "./actions";
  import FormField from "../formComponents/formField";
  import TextField from "../formComponents/textField";
  import StaticText from "../formComponents/staticText";

  import reducer from "../address/reducer";

  export const Address = props => {
    const {
      initialValues,
      handleSuburbSearch,
      companyValue,
      onSuburbStateChange,
      updatePostcodeValue,
      addressData,
      sectionPrefix
    } = props;

    const { reset } = props;

    {
      console.log("PROPS ADDRESS DATA: ", props.stateData);

      console.log("PROPS INITIALVALIES: ", props.initialValues);

      console.log("COMPANY VALUE: ", companyValue);
    }

    return (
      <Panel header={<h3>Client - Address Details</h3>}>
        <Row>
          <Field
            component={TextField}
            name="address1"
            id="address1"
            type="text"
            label="Address Line 1"
            placeholder="Enter street 1st line..."
            fieldCols={6}
            labelCols={3}
            controlCols={9}
          />
          <Field
            component={TextField}
            name="address2"
            id="address2"
            type="text"
            label="Address Line 2"
            placeholder="Enter street 2nd line..."
            fieldCols={6}
            labelCols={3}
            controlCols={9}
          />
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Field
            component={props => {
              const { input, id, placeholder, type } = props;
              const {
                fieldCols,
                labelCols,
                controlCols,
                label,
                inputClass
              } = props;

              // The props we want the inner Select textbox to have.
              const { name, onChange } = input;
              const onStateChange = state => {
                console.log("onStateChange", state);
                onChange(state);
              };

              return (
                <FormField
                  id={id}
                  label={label}
                  fieldCols={fieldCols}
                  labelCols={labelCols}
                  controlCols={controlCols}
                  inputClass={inputClass}
                >
                  <Select
                    name={name}
                    onChange={onStateChange}
                    placeholder="Select state"
                    valueKey="id"
                    options={addressData.states}
                    labelKey="stateLabel"
                    optionRenderer={option =>
                      `${option.stateShortName} (${option.stateName})`}
                    value={input.value}
                    selectValue={
                      Array.isArray(input.value) ? input.value : undefined
                    }
                  />
                </FormField>
              );
            }}
            name="state"
            id="state"
            label="State."
            fieldCols={6}
            labelCols={3}
            controlCols={6}
          />
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Field
            component={props => {
              const { input, id, placeholder, type } = props;
              const {
                fieldCols,
                labelCols,
                controlCols,
                label,
                inputClass
              } = props;

              // The props we want the inner Select.Async textbox to have.
              const { name, value, onChange, onBlur, onFocus } = input;

              // A suburb was selected so "onChange" is updated along
              //with the static form component "Postcode".
              const onSuburbChange = value => {
                onSuburbStateChange(value);
                input.onChange(value);
                updatePostcodeValue(value ? value.postcode : null, sectionPrefix);
              };

              return (
                <FormField
                  id={id}
                  label={label}
                  fieldCols={fieldCols}
                  labelCols={labelCols}
                  controlCols={controlCols}
                  inputClass={inputClass}
                >
                  <Select.Async
                    {...input}
                    onChange={onSuburbChange}
                    placeholder="Select suburb"
                    valueKey="id"
                    labelKey="suburbName"
                    value={input.value}
                    loadOptions={handleSuburbSearch}
                    backspaceRemoves={true}
                  />
                </FormField>
              );
            }}
            name="suburb"
            id="suburb"
            label="Suburb."
            fieldCols={6}
            labelCols={3}
            controlCols={9}
          />
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Field
            component={StaticText}
            name="postcode"
            id="postcode"
            label="Postcode."
            fieldCols={6}
            labelCols={3}
            controlCols={9}
          />
        </Row>
      </Panel>
    );
  };
  Address.propTypes = {
    handleSuburbSearch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onSuburbStateChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  const AddressForm = reduxForm({
    form: "Address"
  })(Address);

  let AddressForm2 = connect(
    (state, ownProps) => ({
      initialValues: state.editClient, // pull initial values from client reducer
      enableReinitialize: true
    }),
    { reducer } // bind client loading action creator
  )(AddressForm);

  export default Address;
```

**state.editClient from the Redux tool in Chrome:**

Note that `address1`, `suburb` and `postcode` all have values and its these that are not being displayed in the `Address` component...

[image]

Comment: Hi @si2030 , did you get your answer ? I am stucked on something similar...